# Including typed.js in wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I have been trying to add a typed.js plugin to one of the wordpress themes.

I put the typed.js in the "js" folder in the theme folder.
Then I edited the functions.php in the theme folder and added:

```
function typed_script_init() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'typedJS', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/typed.js');
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'typed_script_init');

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'typed_init_in_footer');

function typed_init_in_footer() {
        add_action('print_footer_scripts', 'typed_init');
    }
function typed_init() { ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function(){
                $("#typed").typed({
                    strings: ["Are you Interested?"],
                    typeSpeed: 20
                });
            });
    </script>
<?php }
```

I do have in one of my section in the theme:

```
<h1>
    <span id="typed"></span>
</h1>
```

And when I launch my wordpress page it does not work.
I have been sitting on this for almost 3hours reading online tutorials about including javascript in wordpress and still nothing.

Is there anybody who can help me?
Thanks guys!

Comment: I found that you can't use $ sign at the beginning of the function so I deleted it. But still - no results.

Comment: Your browser console should tell you what's wrong, in this instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proper way to do this would be to (1) include jQuery as a dependency (you haven't mentioned if you've included jQuery), (2) use [noConflict wrappers](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#jQuery_noConflict_Wrappers):

```
function typed_script_init() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'typedJS', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/typed.js', array('jquery') );
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'typed_script_init');

function typed_init() {
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">
            (function($){
              // The `$` jQuery shortcut is now available to you
              $(function(){
                $("#typed").typed({
                  strings: ["Are you Interested?"],
                  typeSpeed: 20
                });
              });
            })(jQuery);
          </script>';
}
add_action('wp_footer', 'typed_init');
```

I've added the scripts to the `wp_footer` action hook...but it may be preferable to put those scripts in an external JS file, and also enqueue them in `wp_enqueue_scripts`, with `typedJS` as a dependency.

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for! Thanks!  

But hmm, what if I want to trigger this while I scroll down the page?  
I added the following lines before calling the function in echo and I'm sure I closed all the brackets - but it is not working.  

    (window).on("scroll", function() {
            var y_scroll_pos = window.pageYOffset;
            var scroll_pos_test = 1000;

            if(y_scroll_pos > scroll_pos_test) {

Comment: You should be using `$(window).on(`...you forgot the `$`. If you're still running into issues, please open up a new question. Thanks.